# React Native, Performance issue - iPhone 7 plus and iPhone 8 plus

Tags: ios, performance, react-native

I am facing a performance issue in the app that I am working on. Would appreciate any help or suggestion.

The issue is only noticed in iPhone 7&8 plus models. Seem to work as expected(without noticeable lag) in other iPhone models and Android.

The app has a Tab Navigator as main launching screen, the third tab, sensors, renders a section list and also does little heavy lifting, in the sense, formatting and rendering the row.
Yet I assume it is not much of work, as it seem to work fine in almost all devices except two models - iPhone7+ and iPhone8+

In those two devices alone, what I understand is the JSThread is getting too busy that the UI is frozen! The List scroll works just fine(Main thread free), but none of the touchable is responding.(until after JSThread is free - really long delay)

When the app works just fine in all other devices, why could this happen in those models alone? Have anyone faced anything similar in these models?

Attaching the behaviour while running the app in iPhone 5s and iPhone 7 plus.

[While running in iPhone 5s](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q5qb610ou07rz7o/5s.mov?dl=0)

[While running in iPhone 7plus](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nmac23aehzi9kg9/7splus.mov?dl=0)

Thanks!!

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? Is the app using maps?